# Store multiple checkbox states (enabled / disabled)

Tags: android, checkbox, save, boolean, sharedpreferences

I am making an application when I select certain checkboxes are going enabling other checkboxes, and I would like to keep those states. I'm trying to use sharedPreferences, but it is not giving me results, I do not know why. Someone could help me with the code?

Saving states:

```
private void saveContadors() {
    saved=true;
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("c0", contador0.isEnabled());
    editor.putBoolean("c1", contador1.isEnabled());
    editor.putBoolean("c2", contador2.isEnabled());
    editor.putBoolean("c3", contador3.isEnabled());
    editor.putBoolean("c4", contador4.isEnabled());
    editor.putBoolean("c5", contador5.isEnabled());
    editor.putBoolean("c6", contador6.isEnabled());
    editor.putBoolean("c7", contador7.isEnabled());
    editor.putBoolean("c8", contador8.isEnabled());
    editor.putBoolean("c9", contador9.isEnabled());
    editor.putBoolean("c10", contador10.isEnabled());
    editor.putBoolean("c11", contador11.isEnabled());
    editor.putBoolean("c12", contador12.isEnabled());
    editor.commit();
}
```

Loading states:

```
private void loadContadors() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "load"+contador6.isEnabled(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(saved==true){
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        /*for (int i = 0; i < contador.length; i++)
            contador[i].setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("contador" + i, true));*/
        contador0.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("c0", false));
        contador1.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("c1", false));
        contador2.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("c2", false));
        contador3.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("c3", false));
        contador4.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("c4", false));
        contador5.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("c5", false));
        contador6.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("c6", false));
        contador7.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("c7", false));
        contador8.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("c8", false));
        contador9.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("c9", false));
        contador10.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("c10", false));
        contador11.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("c11", false));
        contador12.setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("c12", false));



          for(i=0;i<contador.length;i++){
                if(contador[i].isEnabled()){
                    contador[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.amarillo);
                }

                if(contador[i].isEnabled() && contador[i].isChecked()){
                    contador[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.naranja);          
                }   

                if(!contador[i].isEnabled()){
                    contador[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gris); 
                }

                if(contador[i].isEnabled() && !contador[i].isChecked()){
                    contador[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.amarillo);
                    }
                }

    }
}
```

And calling these methods:

```
    @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveContadors();
    Toast.makeText(this, "save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    loadContadors();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    saveContadors();
    Toast.makeText(this, "save"+contador6.isEnabled(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

I want to keep if enabled or disabled. I do not want to save if selected.

Comment: editor.commit(); is missing

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put that, but it wasn't the problem. It doesn't  work anyway (I edited the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was fine. The mistake was not having saved the boolean "saved"!. A fool mistake. The code would look like this:

```
private void saveContadors() {
        saved=true;
```

...

```
private void loadContadors() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        saved=prefs.getBoolean("saved", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CheckBoxPreference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html

It's baked into the default SharedPreferences so it makes updating prefs a breeze.

Comment: Do you know if It is the only way? becouse I should change much of my code

Comment: @PabloVillar Since you have many checkboxes I suggest to use  this or SQLiteDatabase


  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: No, it is not the only way, but this is not very much code - why not use the cleanest solution possible?